# Linq with Contains in MultiPart Where

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a Linq Query that I need help with...  I basically have a list of INT that I want to filter on /include in my final list.

Part 1 returns a list of userIDs that are Int which is the correct list I want....

```
    List<int> uids = (from p in context.userid
                      where p.sSurrogateID == id && p.sView
                      select p.sParentID).ToList();
```

I then want to use this list to filter part 2 of my search...

```
var query = from p in context.Clients
            join e in context.Properties on p.cClientID equals e.pClientID
            where p.cLastName.StartsWith(lastname) || p.cSpouseLastName.StartsWith(lastname)  &&  p.cEmployeeID.Contains(uids) {{ THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK  - the filter on UIDs throws error}}
            select new 
            {
                ClientID = p.cClientID,
                PropertyID = e.pPropertyID,
            };

var s = query.ToList();
```

OR I Can filter on this after query if I could figure i t out...

I have tried this in the where clause and it wont compile...

'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for 'contains' and no extension method 'contains' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I think you have it backward.  Shouldn't it be uids.contains(...

Answer (score 1):

You should call `Contains` on your list, not on the element you're looking for:

```
where p.cLastName.StartsWith(lastname) || p.cSpouseLastName.StartsWith(lastname) && uids.Contains(p.cEmployeeID)
```

It will be translated into `IN` clause within your SQL query.